# Argparse append action with default value only if argument doesn't appear

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, argparse

I'm parsing CLI arguments in my program with the `argparse` library. I would like to parse an argument that can repeat, with the following behaviour:

- if the argument appears at least once, its values are stored in a list,
- if the argument doesn't appear, the value is some default list.

I have the following code so far:

```
import argparse
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Change channel colours.")
ap.add_argument('-c', '--channel', action='append', default=['avx', 'fbx'])
print(ap.parse_known_args(['-c', 'iasdf', '-c', 'fdas']))
print(ap.parse_known_args())
```

This appropriately sets a default list, however it doesn't start with an empty list when the argument appears. In other words, the second `print` statement prints the correct value (the default list), but the first one prints

```
['avx', 'fbx', 'iasdf', 'fdas']
```

instead of

```
['iasdf', 'fdas']
```

Is there a way in `argparse` to do what I want without doing something like

```
if len(args.channel) > 2:
    args.channel = args.channel[2:]
```

after the fact?

Comment: 1. You can do the other way around - remove the default value from the parser itself and later just check and append defaults if empty. 2. You could probably try, like, a mutually exclusive group with the same target? Real `-c` would have empty default, and the dummy one would have real default value? I'm not sure this will work. I'm gonna play with this idea and return to you

Comment: 3. "You may also specify an arbitrary action by passing an Action subclass or other object that implements the same interface. The recommended way to do this is to extend Action, overriding the `__call__` method and optionally the `__init__` method." + Docs on `Action` itself: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.Action

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a bug/issue discussing this behavior.  I wrote several posts to that.

https://bugs.python.org/issue16399 argparse: append action with default list adds to list instead of overriding

For now the only change is in documentation, not in behavior.

All defaults are placed in the namespace at the start of parsing.  For ordinary actions, user values overwrite the default.  But in the append case, they are just added to what's there already.  It doesn't try to distinguish between values placed by the default, and previous user values.

I think the simplest solution is to leave the default as is, and check after parsing for `None` or empty list (I don't recall which), and insert your default.  You don't get extra points for doing all the parsing in `argparse`.  A bit of post parsing processing is quite ok.